# Importing a csv file from s3 into rds PostgreSQL Database > Error: schema "aws_commons does not exist

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The following are the steps I have taken:

Followed the guide to create and connect PostgreSQL Database >
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/ > *this was successful.*

Followed

1. Install the required PostgreSQL extensions. These include the aws_s3 and aws_commons extensions.
                                                                                                       `CREATE EXTENSION aws_s3 CASCADE;`
2. Identify the database table and Amazon S3 file to use.
    `CREATE TABLE t1 (col1 varchar(80), col2 varchar(80), col3 varchar(80));`
3. Use the aws_commons.create_s3_uri function to create an aws_commons._s3_uri_1 structure to hold the Amazon S3 file information.
    `SELECT aws_commons.create_s3_uri( 'random', 'test.csv', 'us-east-1' ) AS s3_uri`

> **Error: schema "aws_commons does not exist"**

When I run the following code to identify extensions: `Select * from pg_available_extensions where name like '%aws%'`

| name | installed version | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aws_commons | 1.1 | Common data types across AWS services |
| aws_s3 | 1.1 | AWS S3 extension for importing data from s3 |

4.**IAM**

- Created an IAM policy that provides access to the Amazon S3 bucket(Service:S3, Access level:List,read,write,tagging,permission management).
- Created an IAM role and attached the policy to the role.
- Then assigned the IAM role to the DB instance.

Comment: The error is presumably: `Error: schema "aws_commons" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

Used the wrong guide, solved by Configuring SQL Workbench/J to use a Redshift driver.
See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html 
Then use the copy command.
see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html